# Header and pointer of the Mat object in Open CV?

Tags: opencv

What does the **Header** and **pointer** term means in Mat, please elaborate me on each one through some example.

Comment: I have some questions to you - 1. What are you going to do with tons of questions that you asked before? 2. What is the **header** of object? 3. Maybe you mean **pointer to** object not **pointer of** object?

Comment: @Astor i want to know clearly about the term Header and Pointer used with Mat, i want to some elaborate me through example

Comment: And what about the first question?

Answer (score 1):

After some googling I found answer to your question in [this article](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#mat):

> Mat is basically a class having two data parts: the matrix header
>   (containing information such as the size of the matrix, the method
>   used for storing, at which address is the matrix stored and so on) and
>   a pointer to the matrix containing the pixel values (may take any
>   dimensionality depending on the method chosen for storing) .

Comment: @PirFahimShah was this answer correct? If yes than you should accept it otherwise tell me what you don't understand.